# Modify the default created README.md in GitLab when a new project is created

Tags: gitlab, markdown, readme

I have a locally hosted GitLab omnibus instance running in a docker container.

When a project is created through the web front end, it creates a default README.md from somewhere. I'd like to modify that default file to better suit our project work flow and enable the engineer to fill out the necessaries about their project with some consistency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

files you are looking for are here:

- embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/views/projects/readme_templates/default.md.tt
- embedded/service/gitlab-rails/app/experiments/templates/new_project_readme_content/readme_advanced.md.tt.